# Trigger's not responding how I want in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I need help with a game I am creating. I am building the game with the Unity engine and am pretty new to C# coding. I am creating a 2d game where the player controls the color of a square and must change it to the correct color as when it passes a certain colored object. The player changes colors great and the objects are triggers. When a player passes the trigger if its not the right color the player dies. Well that works perfect but only for the first object the next one no matter the color of the player the object dies. I have tried if's in if statements and else if's I can't seem to figure it out. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code for the player

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.transform.tag == "Blue") {
        blue = true;
    }
    else {
        blue=false;
    }

    if (other.transform.tag == "Red") {
        red = true;
        } 
    else {
        red =false;
    }

    if (other.transform.tag == "Blue" && GameObject.Find ("Blue").GetComponent<Blue> ().mb == false) {
                    yield return 0;
                    Die ();
    } else if (other.transform.tag == "Red" && GameObject.Find ("Red").GetComponent<Red> ().mr == false) {
                    Die ();     
    }

}
```

Here is the code for each different colored object. This one happens to be blue.

```
void Update () {
    if (GameObject.Find ("Player").GetComponent<Movement> ().blue == true && GameObject.Find ("Player").GetComponent<Movement> ().playerBlue == true) {
                    mb = true;  
            } else {
        mb = false;         
    }
    if (!GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Movement>().blue) {
        mb = false; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your execution order is a little messy, that's probably why it's not working. Try to make all your logic follow one path, not two. Right now, you are:

- (1)Colliding, (2) setting some boolean variables, (3)checking some variables, (4)optionally dying.
- At a separate time in a separate class, set the boolean that was set in step 1 and setting the variable that's checked in step 3

This is what we call spaghetti code. It's all twisted together. Can you think of a way to untangle it, so the two bits of logic don't mutually depend on each other?

For example, I see in the latter block of code, you're checking whether the player is blue. Could you instead run that code when the player sets `blue` (or sets `blue=false`)?

Edit: I know this isn't strictly answering your question, but this untangling is the first step of the problem solving process.